# React setState (useState hook) of array change position of object element

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, setstate

I have an array of objects and I want to place a specific object at first position by his index

```
[{name: objec1, index: 1}, {name: objec2, index: 2}, {name: object3, index: 3}]
```

What I want is to set the state with object2 for example at first position. My code:

```
setObjectsState(prevState => ({ ...prevState[objectIndex], ...prevState.filter((object, i) => i === objectIndex) }));
```

Answer (score 1):

You’re close, but you’re returning an object instead of an array. You'll also want to change the operator in the filter method to only return objects that aren't the one you're placing at the start of the array.

This should fix it:

```js
setObjectsState(prevState => ([
  { ...prevState[objectIndex] },
  ...prevState.filter((object, i) => i !== objectIndex)
]));
```